# A start job for dev-mapper-cryptswap.device is never ending

Tags: boot, 16.04, swap, cryptsetup

I again have problems with my swap.
I using an encrypted swapfile. It worked until i rebooted my PC. When im trying to boot it is just showing this:
[image: Boot problem]
I disabled my swap in the recovery mode for now. But i am really confused why it has this boot problem.

/etc/fstab:

```
UUID=479cf731-657a-4f19-bd30-975b4019299f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/AAE010E1E010B613 /mnt/AAE010E1E010B613 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap none swap sw 0 0
```

/etc/crypttab:

```
cryptswap /swapfile /dev/urandom swap
```

If any further information is needed, let me know and I will post it.

Comment: This occurs occasionally in my system. Last time it occured after I had to force reboot by Alt-PrtScr-{s,u,b} when resume from suspend to RAM did not work. Rebooting by Ctrl-Aly-Del helped.

Comment: BTW how do you know it will never end?

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @jarno helped a lot. 
Instead of killing the machine with a hard power down, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html) manual - "If this signal is received more than 7 times per 2s, an immediate reboot is triggered."